# How I can translate integer value into other locale

Tags: google-translate

I want to translate integer into Hindi integer symbols like

1  ->   १
2  ->   २
when I tried to translate integer into different locale it will give the same value as original value. pls let me know if there is any solution regarding it you have implement earlier